# How can I do a query for this report in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this tables "CashMovementTbl","SalesTbl" & "ExpensesTbl" which include data like that:

[image]

And I want to show my data such as following:

[image]

So how can I do a query in SQL Server to show data like that.

Comment: Your question seems to be missing the tables and desired result.  Also seems to be missing what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
   c.CashDate,
   ISNULL(s.BillNo,e.ExpnsType) As Details,
   CASE WHEN c.SaleID IS NOT NULL THNE c.Amount ELSE 0 END AS [In],
   CASE WHEN c.ExpenseID IS NOT NULL THNE c.Amount ELSE 0 END AS [Out] 
FROM CashMovementTbl c
LEFT JOIN SalesTbl s
 ON c.SaleID = s.SalesIS
LEFT JOIN ExpensensTbl e
 ON c.ExpenseID = e.ExpnsID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot EricZ , that 's help me